# Programmatically control a Mac cursor in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

There are a bunch of apps on the App Store that allow you to control your Mac's cursor - you install the app on your iPhone and some client software on your Mac, and then as you move your finger around on your phone and it controls your Mac through bluetooth.

My question is, how is this done? Not on the iOS side, but on the Mac side. How do you programmatically change the position of the cursor on a Mac?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated by @H2C03, you can do that via `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()`, however you will only be able to warp the mouse location every 250 milliseconds (0.25 seconds).  In order to get around that, you have to add a bit of extra code in order to continuously warp the mouse.

```
NSPoint mouseWarpLocation = NSMakePoint(100, 100);

CGEventSourceRef evsrc = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(evsrc, 0.0);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (0);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(mouseWarpLocation);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (1);
CFRelease(evsrc);
```

Comment: I was just testing this out and it works well, but how could I get it so that it continuously updates? For example, if the user moves their finger to the right on one of those apps I was talking about in the original post, how can you continuously update the cursor to follow the finger?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here (and I'm not too familiar with iOS as well), but perhaps normalize the finger position on the iOS device screen, then translate it back to the screen coordinates on the mac?

Comment: That might work; basically, I'm asking how the trackpad works. You move your finger up, and irrelevant of where your finger starts or ends, the cursor moves up that distance scaled to the size of your screen (or number of pixels, or whatever). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Oh I see, when you move your trackpad/mouse, there will be an acceleration level to it, so for the same real distance on your trackpad/mouse, depending on how fast or slow you move it, the distance the cursor travels will be different so there's a bit of calculation to that, however I'm not sure the exact algorithm of determining the cursor moved.  Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I just have one more quick question: for the sake of testing, I used `-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event` to determine when a key was pressed, and made it such that when I press the right arrow, the mouse moves to the right by this code: `NSPoint mouseWarpLocation = NSMakePoint(mPoint.x+20, mPoint.y);` (all your other code is the same). The cursor moves to the right, but for some reason it also hops back and forth across the centerline as it moves... do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: `-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event` is called continuously at the same rate of the key repeat in the users system preferences, so you'll probably want to have an ivar or global variable that records if the key is already pressed.

Comment: I am able to get X and Y position of finger on mac app but I don't know how to map finger movement to mouse position… Any help

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer - so that anyone who copies-and-pastes this code is saved from memory leaks, please add this to your code snippet at the bottom: CFRelease(evsrc);

Answer (score 1):

CoreGraphics can do it - specifically, you're looking for the `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()` function. Quartz (CoreGraphics) [display services documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html) here.

Example: move the cursor to the center of the screen:

```
CGDirectDisplayID displayID = CGMainDisplayID();
size_t screenWidth = CGDisplayPixelsWide(displayID);
size_t screenHeight = CGDisplayPixelsHigh(displayID);
CGPoint centerOfScreen = CGPointMake(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(centerOfScreen);
```

Comment: I am able to get X and Y position of finger on mac app but I don't know how to map finger movement to mouse position… Any help